# how to interpret this crash log of iphone

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004420 objc_msgSend + 24
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x000042a6 CFRetain + 54
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000a9f0 __CFBasicHashStandardRetainValue + 8
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x000054c0 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00006184 CFBasicHashAddValue + 276
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x00006cfe CFDictionaryCreate + 58
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x00033d7c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 1456
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x000361bc -[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 776
    8   iota                            0x0000cb04 -[CorpDirViewController reloadDisplayList] (CorpDirViewController.m:833)
    9   iota                            0x000098ba -[CorpDirViewController refreshDataAndDisplay] (CorpDirViewController.m:134)
    10  iota                            0x00009b62 -[CorpDirViewController handleNotication:] (CorpDirViewController.m:197)
    11  Foundation                      0x00015432 _nsnote_callback + 150
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x000271da __CFXNotificationPost_old + 390
    13  CoreFoundation                  0x00026e7a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 122
    14  Foundation                      0x0000b9f6 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotification:] + 138
    15  Foundation                      0x0007ae02 postQueueNotifications + 258
    16  Foundation                      0x0007afae __NSPostIdleQueueNotes + 6
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x00031084 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x00030eb2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 494
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x00028206 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x00027d74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x00027c82 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
    22  GraphicsServices                0x00004e84 GSEventRunModal + 188
    23  UIKit                           0x00004f8c -[UIApplication _run] + 564
    24  UIKit                           0x000024cc UIApplicationMain + 964
    25  iota                            0x00005582 main (main.m:17)
    26  iota                            0x00005544 0x1000 + 17732
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of the log, you have overreleased something and that is causing a crash. Take a look at this line in your code:

```
8   iota                            0x0000cb04 -[CorpDirViewController reloadDisplayList] (CorpDirViewController.m:833)
```

Which has the file and the line of code affected:

```
[CorpDirViewController reloadDisplayList] (CorpDirViewController.m:833)
```